Configure multiple instances on a SQL Availability group cluster
I need some guidance please.
My Distributed AG configuration is to be with:

Two SQL 2022 named instances each with its own AG and AG listener on the Primary Cluster
hence two DAGs on the one cluster

In order to ensure that clients connect to the right instance, I need some guidance on the network configuration please. My thoughts are:

to use static ports for the two named instances so that the firewall can be configured to allow access to them

Run SQL Browser to listen on port TCP 1434 and direct client connection to the right instance

Run the two named instances on different tcp ports i.e. TCP 1433 and 1435 respectively

I am however not sure about the listeners. Do I leave them both on port TCP 1433 or do I need them on 1433 & 1435 as well?


I am trying to ensure each underlying AG is correctly configured so that each of the two DAGs works correctly.
I'd appreciate some helpful thoughts on this configuration please.
Thank you.
